# OneDrive Policy for user and Teams folders in business account

Tags: group-policy, onedrive-for-business

My organization has acquired a lot of Microsoft Cloud services (Teams, SharePoint Online, OneDrive, Office 365). All our users have a OneDrive account, but they are not all using it yet. Additionally, some users have added a link to their Teams channel file share into their Windows Explorer menu (it shows after the user's OneDrive share).  This was done by opening the teams channel in SharePoint and Syncing the channel. Users could browse files and folders in the Teams share and mark any they choose to for keeping a local copy.

I was tasked to create a policy that keeps users' files on their local computer while copying and syncing the files up to their OneDrive Cloud. This was not hard to accomplish.

But the users that have a Teams channel file share synced to their Windows Explorer. The Teams channel share was treated like the personal OneDrive. A local copy of every file and folder in the Teams share was downloaded to their local computers.

Is there not a way to have separate settings for these? I'd like the Teams channels to be browsable in Explorer and users able to mark any files or folders that they choose to for keeping a local copy.

Thanks in advance.